# Random featured image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image, twentytwenty

I would like to randomize featured image from selection on my wordpress. I have a chid theme twenty twnenty. I tried several plugins an does't work.

I need help!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://www.quickfeaturedimages.com/pro-vs-free/

though not sure if can select from a predefined set on a per-post basis